# Is it possible to show some markers on click on a specific button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, maps

I would like to know if there is a way to group markers to display them when clicking on certain buttons for a better readability of the map.
For example on my map, I have markers ''Private Cloud - XXX'' that I would like to display when clicking on the corresponding button ''Private Cloud Regions'' in the interface.
Currently, the markers are displayed by default when the map is opened....
Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/paul-k/full/gOmXZxE

Here is one of my markers

```
var markerFrance = new L.marker([45.777222 , 3.087025], {
        opacity: 0.01
      });
      markerFrance.bindTooltip("Public Cloud - France ", {
        interactive: true,
        permanent: true,
        className: "zone-marker marker-border salmonu-border",
        direction: 'center'
      });
      markerFrance.addTo(map);
      markerFrance.on('click', function(e)
```

And here is one of the button i want it to show the markers:

```
<button id="regionspublic" class="btn-square salmonu-border grow" data-target="#square5">Public Cloud Locations</button>

 <div class="square-info salmon-border" id="square5">
    <a href="#" class="close-classic"></a>
    <div class="content">
      <h3><strong><span style="font-size: 20px;"><span style="font-family: Montserrat;">Public Cloud Locations</span></span></strong></h3>
      <p><span style="font-size: 12px;"><strong><span style="font-family: Montserrat;">GTS provides a range of services to enable the group Business Units to consume Amazon AWS and Microsoft AZURE public cloud services in a governed and secure manner and to take advantage of best-of-breed hybrid and cloud native solutions. </span></strong></span></p>
      <strong><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="" width="300" height="140" /> </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content"><strong></strong>
      <p><span style="font-size: 12px;"><strong><span style="font-family: Montserrat;">Due to security reasons, Public Cloud Availability Zones are approximately displayed!</span></strong></span></p>
      <p><span style="font-size: 12px;"><strong><span style="font-family: Montserrat;">A GTS team named&nbsp;Public Cloud Center of Excellence (CoE)&nbsp;is responsible for the delivery and operations of security and control services for the Public Cloud. In addition, the CoE is responsible for the Professional Services activities and for supporting customers in their transformation to the Public Cloud.</span></strong></span></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need CSS. Whatever ID or class you are using for the buttons, just add the following code to their style file:

```css
.animated_div {
 width:60px;
 height:40px;
 background:#92B901;
 color:#ffffff;
 position:absolute;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:15px;
 padding:10px;
float:left;
margin:5px;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s,opacity 1s,background 1s,width 1s,height 1s,font-size 1s;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-o-transition-property:width,height,-o-transform,background,font-size,opacity;
-o-transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;
-moz-transition-property:width,height,-o-transform,background,font-size,opacity;
-moz-transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;
transition-property:width,height,transform,background,font-size,opacity;
transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;
border-radius:5px;
opacity:0.4;
}
.animated_div:hover
{
opacity:1;
background:#1ec7e6;
width:130px;
height:80px;
font-size:35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated_div">CSS</div>
```

Now that seems good and readable right?

Comment: Hi! Thank's for the answer but i think this is to show buttons on click on a marker, i want the opposite way! When i click on one of my button, a specific group or markers appears!

Comment: Just replace :hover with :active then. You will then accomplish this by clicking on the button